# Atmel AVR Studio 6 - remove invalid target device - how?

Tags: avr, atmel-studio

Okay, so I had an STK500 driver connected on USB on virtual COM3. However, after installing and uninstalling some software, the drivers futz'd up, and ceased to detect the programmer.

So, I've reinstalled STK500 drivers, and set device to use COM4, as COM3 appeared to be in use and couldn't be re-selected.

Now, Atmel studio 6, under tools / Device Programming, there's STK500 on both COM3 and COM4. It's annoying, as for some reason my project tries to use COM3 instead of COM4 when clicking 'Debug'.

How can I delete the COM3 device from there? I can add devices under Tools / Add target, but I can't find anything like 'Delete target' anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked Device Manager? (The Windows OS, not Atmel Studio.)

Comment: Are you sure COM3 couldn't be selected? I've seen the "(in use)" before with other USB COM port devices and it just gives you a warning it might not work but lets you go ahead. Normally it does work OK, unless of course it's a different device with the port allocated and you plug it in at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

**View** -> **Available Atmel Tools** -> *Right click on target* -> **Remove**

Answer (score -1):

If you're still looking for a way to REMOVE / DELETE an unused Tool, choose View => Available Atmel Tools and then right-click the one you want to remove & choose Remove.

Comment: How does this answer improve on the other one from 4.5 years ago?